# How can I add a get the CommandBarControl of a default button in Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm trying to add a ClickEventHandler to a button to the "Invite Attendees" button found on the "New Appointment" form. However before I can do this I need a control to add the event too. In order to get this control, so far I've been trying to use `Inspector.CommandBars.FindControl()` without much luck. The documentation hasn't been much help to me either (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core._commandbars.findcontrol.aspx). Where am I supposed to get the ID of the control from if I don't already have the control?!

Thanks for any help. ☺

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply not possible. The closest you can get to this is adding your own button and adding event handlers to that.